# react : array state is not iterable

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

I have this array state :

```
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);
```

I want every time I add a player, to add the new value in addition to the previous ones
so I did this:

```
  const addPlayerHandler = (name) => {
    setPlayers({ players: [...players, name] });
  };
```

when I add the first value works fine, but the second value it gives me error : players is not iterable, when did arrays become uniterable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Players is an array, not an object, you can do:
setPlayers( [...players, name] );

Comment: This gives the same error

Answer (score 1):

What's your data structure?

Like this?

```
[{ name: 'player 11',  }]
```

if above, try `setPlayers({ players: [...players, { name }] });`

Answer (score 0):

Your `setPlayers()` assigns an object (with `players` as a key) as a value to the `players` variable.

Instead, what you are looking for is `setPlayers(prevPlayers => [...prevPlayers, name])`

So you need to assign an array instead of an object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:-

```
 const [player, setPlayer] = useState({});
 const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);

 const addPlayerHandler = (name,e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (name.trim() !== "") {
        const newPlayer = {
          player_id: `p_${Date.now()}`,
          player_name: name,
       };
       const palyersList = [...players];
       palyersList.push(newPlayer);
       setPlayer({});
       setPlayers(palyersList);
     } 
     else {
       setPlayer({});
       console.log(`error`,"Invalid or Empty Player Details");
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it was because I used useEffect() on window load to set state to the JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("array") so my array was essentially turning into an Object and that's why it was not iterable